# Can I boot from a SD Card  on a Dell Mini 9?

Tags: boot, live-usb, boot-failure, sd-card

I have installed from the live USB (with Persistance) onto an SD Card.

But when I reboot, even though I have selected USB devices in the Boot selection menu I get an OS not found error...

Has anyone suceeded in doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The BIOS for the Mini 9 doesn't allow it to boot off of an SD card.  You could burn it onto a USB stick instead and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also insert the SD card in a memory (multi) card reader, link it to the computer with an USB wire, and boot from there.

Comment: whether you can boot from SD card or not depends on the SD card reader and the BIOS. [How do I install Ubuntu 16.04 from an SD card?](https://askubuntu.com/a/872629/253474)