# Installing Ubuntu using DOS without external drive or CD

Tags: system-installation

Is there a way to install Ubuntu on laptop equipped only With DOS without the aid of a bootable drive, or CD  ? (I already have the ISO file on my other laptop)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872622/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-16-04-from-an-sd-card

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu 16.04 from an SD card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872622/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-16-04-from-an-sd-card)

Answer (score 2):

Installing Ubuntu on a laptop is independent of what is installed in its internal drive. The internal drive can be completely empty.

If the internal drive is empty or DOS is installed you need another computer to make a DVD disk, USB pendrive or memory card bootable with a live Ubuntu system.

Most tools to make a live Ubuntu system need Linux, Windows or MacOS. Maybe you can borrow a computer for that purpose, or in the worst case buy a DVD disk or USB pendrive with a live Ubuntu system already installed.

See this official Ubuntu 'download/install' link,

[Ubuntu downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download)

- Most people select [Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Scroll down to find instructions how to install Ubuntu Desktop from Ubuntu, Windows or MacOS.
- But don't forget the [Ubuntu flavours](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-flavours) (with different desktop environments).
- If you want [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), you know it already.

See also this link: [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)
.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that you can accomplish this **without the aid of a bootable drive, or CD in your laptop**, all of which require you to have access to another more current system. If the system you have has USB ports and the ability to boot from them via BIOS setting or has an optical drive you can use one of the [common installation methods.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) **If neither of these options are available to you** since most hardware is supported by the kernel you can simply take your existing drive out of the laptop, connect it to a more current system (via an adapter if necessary) and then install it to that drive using the more current system that you have obtained using the [common installation methods.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

You could also clone an existing installation to your existing drive provided that it matches the capabilities of the target system.